# jquery $variable check is attribute is equal to

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/2Wpfw/16/

This seems really trivial question but I cannot for the life work this one out.

I have this jQuery var...

```
var $selectArea = $("ul#1 li input[type='checkbox'],
ul#2 li input[type='checkbox'], ul#3 li input[type='checkbox']");
```

and I want to run this...

```
$selectArea.closest('li').addClass('box-checked');
```

but only if the `$selectArea` attribute `checked` is `"checked"` - pretty simple right?

So I've tried this...

```
if ( $selectArea.attr("checked") == "checked" ) {

    $selectArea.closest('li').addClass('box-checked');

}
```

and...

```
$selectArea.filter('[checked="checked"]').closest('li').addClass('box-checked');
```

and this... (but think im sniffing up the wrong tree here)

```
$selectArea.is('[checked="checked"]').closest('li').addClass('box-checked');
```

And ideas would be awesome thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/2Wpfw/16/

Comment: A few tips: IDs may not start with a number, and you can simplify as `$("ul#a, ul#b").find("li input[type='checkbox']")`.

Comment: Thanks did not know that. Its just in my fiddle but good to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're doing it inside the `change` event for the checkbox. Go ahead an check one of the checkboxes - it will have the class added.

I would make the code that you want to happen to checked checkboxes a separate function so you can easily call it `onload` and `onchange` and have the same results.

Heres an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Wpfw/18/) showing you what I mean.

```
// reusable function
function check($elem)
{
    $elem.closest('li').toggleClass('box-checked', this.checked)
}

$selectArea.on('change', function() {
    check($(this));
});

$(function(){
    // onload get all checked inputs via the :checked selector 
    check($('input:checked'));
});
```

​

Comment: Thank you @Snuffleupagus this is a gem. Great overall solution to my problem. Again, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried $selectArea.is(':checked') [http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)/

Comment: @Joshc `.is` returns a boolean, so it would be `if($selectArea.is('checked') // action here`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$selectArea.each( function(i,e) {
    if ( $(e).is(':checked') ) {    
        $(e).closest('li').addClass('box-checked');
    }
});
```

As you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/75kPU/3/